# Touch screen mouse messages and LLMHF_INJECTED flag

Tags: windows, winapi, touch, mouse, hook

Using low level mouse hook `SetWindowsHookEx` with `WH_MOUSE_LL` parameter, I found that all mouse messages sent by real mouse have no Injected flag. When mouse messages are sent by touch screen (by tapping the screen), Injected flag is set.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ( nCode < 0 )
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(g_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    MSLLHOOKSTRUCT* p = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;

    if (p->flags & LLMHF_INJECTED )
    {
        OutputDebugString(L"Injected\n");
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(g_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

"Injected" is printed only when touch screen is tapped. Does this behavior depend on touch screen driver, can I be sure that all touch screens have the same behavior?

Is there any other way to detect the source of mouse message?

Comment: At a guess I'd say it's injected if the window in question hasn't specifically registered for touch input.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I cannot use this flag for touch screen detection.